# Geeting Angular JS JSON object value in MVC @Url.Action helper Method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs

How can I pass an Angular scope value to the rout value object of @Url.Action method?

here is what i have

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Product", new { id = ""})">
   {{product.Name}}
 </a>
```

i want the value of id = product.Id

How can I do that ?

Product object has been defined in the  controller scope and it is a JSON format.

Comment: Angular runs on client side, @Ur.Action is server side processing, they cannot share state. You need to generate this link on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You should you [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

```
<a ng-href="Action("Edit", "Product", ...)">
   {{product.Name}}
 </a>
```

and in controller scope it will be method:

```
$scope.Action = function( ....
```